American crime/military movie about drugs, probably 90s
I remember this movie. The main characters are stoners in the US Army. At one point, during tank maneuver drills one of them goes AWOL and drives through a gas station. I think the main plot was them stealing guns from a truck and trading it for the ingredients to make crystal meth. It was probably from the 90s, but could possibly be late 80s or early 2000s.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Sounds like Buffalo Soldiers from 2001 with Joaquin Phoenix, Ed Harris and Anna Paquin.

The Berlin Wall is about to fall, and the world is about to be made safe for the new world order. But outside of Stuttgart, West Germany, at Theodore Roosevelt Army Base, Specialist Ray Elwood of the 317th Supply Battalion is about to find his own cold war turn white hot. Elwood's a lovable rogue, a conscript who's managed to turn his military servitude into a blossoming network of black market deals, more out of boredom than ambition. Officially, there's his day job as battalion secretary to the inept but caring Commander Wallace Berman. On the side, there's everything from selling the locals stolen Mop'N'Glo to cooking heroin for the base's ruthless head of Military Police, Sgt. Saad.

Here's the scene with the stoned tank crew in the gas station:



